# MySQL insert, update-heavy, sort by index

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-indexes, database-optimization

I'm currently designing a database that has a table `events` that will be insert (and update)-heavy (I predict anywhere between 1,000 and 5,000 inserts per minute), but also needs to be sorted by date.

Each event has a `read` boolean field, `user_id`, and sorts by `updated_at` (datetime) `DESC`. The select statement would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `read`=0 AND `user_id`='<user id>' ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC
```

Right now, I'm thinking of using an index on `read`, `user_id`, and `updated_at` to optimize the fetch & sort, but does this mean that the whole index will be updated on a

```
UPDATE `events` SET `read`='1' WHERE `id`='<event id>'
```

?

What would be the most performance-efficient (insert, update, select) solution in this situation?

Comment: If you are expecting writes that happen on single columns instead of all 3, maybe doing individual indexes on each column instead of one index on all 3 columns.

Comment: Since `user_id` and `updated_at` won't change, should I have a index on those two columns, then a separate index on `read` ?

Comment: It all depends on the majority of the inserts/updates you are running against the database and what gets edited in the same query.

Comment: I'll experiment around with different index structures. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL use only one index per table per query (sometime it use more than one when an index-merge happen) so creating multiples indexes will not speed-up the query.

If I recall correctly it is better to use the most discriminant selector first in an index so a `user_id.read.updated_at` will probably be a good solution.

I don't know if updating an index is very costly or not, but since MySQL indexes are by default a tree if `read` change the engine has just to operate under an `user_id` leaf so maybe the impact is lowered.

Nonetheless you can just have an index on `user_id.updated_at` and leave MySQL filter the `read`, most of the time ordering data from a table is more costly than filtering.

Comment: If MySQL only uses one index per query, then creating a `read` index would just add additional overhead for no performance gain, correct (at least, in this situation)?

Comment: @ypercube Right it is more "one index per table per query", but it is also wrong as a different index can be used for the same table in the same query in case of self-joined table